How to access the Axum request path in a Minijinja template?
I am making a web app using Axum. I want to add attributes and styles to the active links in my Minijinja templates (e.g. aria-current). In order to do this, I need the request path in every single template, including templates for error pages.
What I have so far is in normal pages, I use the OriginalUri extractor to pass the request path into the context. For error pages, I implement IntoResponse for my app error type, which doesn't have access to the request. I thought of updating the minijinja::Environment in middleware, but since I pass it as app state, it is readonly.
How do I ensure every template has access to the request path?
Edit: I couldn't figure out how to reuse the environment from app state in IntoResponse so I recreate the environment for error responses. That's probably not the way it should be done. My AppError looks like this:
enum AppError {
    UnexpectedError(anyhow::Error),
}

impl From<anyhow::Error> for AppError {
    fn from(e: anyhow::Error) -> Self {
        Self::UnexpectedError(e)
    }
}

impl IntoResponse for AppError {
    fn into_response(self) -> Response {
        match self {
            Self::UnexpectedError(_) => {
                let mut env = Environment::new();
                env.set_loader(path_loader("templates"));
                match env
                    .get_template("500.html.j2")
                    .and_then(|tmpl| tmpl.render(context! {}))
                {
                    Ok(content) => {
                        (StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, Html(content)).into_response()
                    }
                    Err(_) => {
                        (StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "We're experiencing unexpected technical difficulties. Please try again later. Thank you for your patience.").into_response()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Please clarify exactly how IntoResponse can access your templates from AppState. Did you add AppState to your app error type?

@FinnBear It can't access AppState. I recreate the environment in the IntoResponse implementation. That's probably wrong. I've updated my question with code

Thanks for clarifying! I've updated my answer to extend ContextualizedError to contain an Arc<Environment> from the AppState. However, a less tedious solution would probably be to abandon IntoResponse and create an error response where you previously called into_response() (where AppState and OriginalUri are directly accessible).

@FinnBear Ok I've changed it so that I'm repeating the same error handling and request path extraction logic in every route. I was hoping there was some mechanism for reducing duplication that I just wasn't aware of

I'm glad you now have something that works :) . If you post an example of the duplication, maybe someone can point out if it isn't a minimum amount of duplication.

@FinnBear I have posted what I ended up with

I assume that axum/examples/templates-minijinja is the template you mean.
Normally you could edit the template context, but you mentioned needing to support IntoResponse, which doesn't have the request or AppState.
If you must use IntoResponse, you could try supplementing your error with additional context, allowing you to pass OriginalUri into the context!:
pub struct ContextualizedError {
    pub error: Error,
    pub original_uri: OriginalUri,
    pub environment: Arc<Environment>,
}

impl IntoResponse for ContextualizedError {
    fn into_response(self) -> Response {
        let Self{error, original_uri, environment} = self;

        let template = environment.get_template("error.txt").unwrap();

        let result = template.render(context! { error => error, path => original_uri.0.path() }).unwrap();
        result.into_response()
    }
}

async fn handler(original_uri: OriginalUri, State(state): State<AppState>) -> Result<(), ContextualizedError> {
    Err(Error::SomethingWentWrong).map_err(
        move |error| ContextualizedError{
            error,
            original_uri,
            environment: state.environment.clone()
        }
    )
}

To avoid redundancy, you could make a middleware that clones the Environment from the AppState, adds the path as a global variable, and stores it as a request extension. You would have to pass the extension contents to your IntoResponse somehow. The issue with this alternative solution is the inefficiency of cloning several internal datastructures inside Environment.
I do not see a way to create a new environment, referencing an old one except for the addition of an extra global variable, which would be needed to do the middleware approach efficiently.
You can also stop using IntoResponse and generate an error Response where you would otherwise call into_response. Note that Response implements IntoResponse.

As Finn Bear suggested, I can abandon the IntoResponse implementation and replace it with an extractor.
#[derive(Clone, FromRef)]
pub(crate) struct AppState {
    pub(crate) db_pool: PgPool,
    pub(crate) template_env: Environment<'static>,
}

pub(crate) struct TemplateEngine {
    env: Environment<'static>,
    request_path: String,
}

impl TemplateEngine {
    pub(crate) fn new(env: Environment<'static>, request_path: &str) -> Self {
        Self {
            env,
            request_path: request_path.into(),
        }
    }

    pub(crate) fn render(&self, name: &str, ctx: Value) -> Response {
        match self
            .env
            .get_template(&format!("{name}.html.j2"))
            .and_then(|tmpl| tmpl.render(context! { request_path => self.request_path, ..ctx }))
        {
            Ok(content) => Html(content).into_response(),
            Err(err) => {
                tracing::error!(%err, "Failed to render template {}", name);
                self.render_error()
            }
        }
    }

    pub(crate) fn render_error(&self) -> Response {
        match self
            .env
            .get_template("500.html.j2")
            .and_then(|tmpl| tmpl.render(context! { request_path => self.request_path }))
        {
            Ok(content) => (StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, Html(content)).into_response(),
            Err(err) => {
                tracing::error!(%err, "Failed to render template '500'");
                (StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "We're experiencing unexpected technical difficulties. Please try again later. Thank you for your patience.").into_response()
            }
        }
    }
}

#[async_trait]
impl<S> FromRequestParts<S> for TemplateEngine
where
    Environment<'static>: FromRef<S>,
    S: Send + Sync,
{
    type Rejection = Infallible;

    async fn from_request_parts(parts: &mut Parts, state: &S) -> Result<Self, Self::Rejection> {
        Ok(Self {
            env: Environment::<'static>::from_ref(state),
            request_path: parts.uri.path().into(),
        })
    }
}

async fn homepage(
    template_eng: TemplateEngine,
    State(db_pool): State<PgPool>,
) -> impl IntoResponse {
    match get_global_feed(&db_pool).await {
        Ok(posts) => template_eng.render("home", context! { posts }),
        Err(err) => {
            tracing::error!(%err, "Failed to fetch global feed posts from database");
            template_eng.render_error()
        }
    }
}


Looks good! I only see one way to reduce per-route duplication. You could create a new extractor (impl FromRequestParts for MyExtractor) which internally extracts and stores the Arc<AppState> and OriginalUri (by duplicating code from the implementations of those extractors). That extractor could have a helper method for rendering a named template with a given context. It could internally use its AppState and OriginalUri to render an error if needed. Each route would use one extractor, do a database lookup, and then call one rendering method on the extractor with the data.
